# Delete request taking too long while the API is working perfectly fine in node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, rest, express

I am working on a react journal/note taking web app where I created the CRUD API for notes which is working fine, but when the I am making a delete request from the frontend it is saying "pending" status on the request and taking too long...

This is the code for backend API :
[image]
This is the code for 'DELETE' request in frontend:
[image]
And this is the network tools and console:
[image]
And I also consol logged the note id at the frontend, and it was the right one so, only the request is the problem so I don't know what to do?

Comment: please post code node images of code ...

Comment: Check at the backend whats taking so long ... Add logging and time measurements

Comment: actually I checked my bakend but didn't find any errors....and only the delete request was not working rest of the request were working fine for the CRUD